# Upsizing Gas Line From Tee

Tags: plumbing, furnace, water-heater, gas, natural-gas

I need to upsize a short 1/2" run to 3/4" (it splits from the main line using a tee). This is about 4-5ft long and goes into an appliance directly. Would it be OK to remove just the pipe and keep the 1/2" tee? I'm thinking not, since the restriction is still there, but not sure if flow would be actually noticeably impacted. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Do you need the change it because the appliance has a 3/4 inch fitting or do you actually need a higher flow of gas?   If the 2nd case, you need to replace the tee of course.

Comment: need a higher flow of gas

Comment: Just a note- not answer to question: 2-part unions like that may not be allowed under certain circumstances, and are always required to be in an "accessible location" when they are allowed (AFAIK). Check with the local AHJ.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a union right there changing the T should not be that tough. There is a nipple to the right if lengths change. I might try the existing But any time another appliance with no restrictions turns on the new one may starve for fuel. I have seen your plan work but since doing it right would not be much more work and possibly only changing the T, I would do that so I would not have to go back and do it over with all the new pipe in place needing to be removed to upgrade the T if it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing that change, I would do the job right and replace the tee. The get the flow you need 1/2" thread may not flow the amount of gas that you need. That said, the distance you need to go with that branch just may still yield enough gas flow to support the device you are connecting. I would use what is there first to see if I get enough gas flow. If you don't, then change that section of pipe.

Comment: I would guess that the T is _not_ a union type fitting with opposite threads at each end. Removing the T would, potentially, require disassembly of a large portion of the downstream piping to get it out, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan - Check the picture. There is a union right next to the T as pointed out in the answer by Ed Beal. Changing any of that piping will be a pain but that union may very well save the day.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @MichaelKaras, I didn't recognize it as such. Nor did I read Ed's post in enough detail to have that register...